# unity Transform position setting boundries in object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a movement where sprites go down in a row inside a panel, and then they stop when reaching the bottom boundry of the panel. Problem is after i set the position of the objects where it has to stop moving, its taking me position.y = 0 as if it was the middle of the screen. How do i set it to stop moving, when reaching the bottom of its parent object (the panel). Thank you.
here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Transform_test : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
SpriteRenderer[] Reels;
[SerializeField]
Transform[] ReelsTransform;
int speed;
bool drop;
[SerializeField]
GameObject Panel;





void Start()
{
    Debug.Log(transform);
    //transform.position = new Vector3 (10,0,0);
    speed = 1;
    drop = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
   // test();

   
    
    
        if (drop == false)
        {
          foreach (Transform Reels in ReelsTransform)//This Targets All Children Objects Of The Main Parent Object
        {
             Debug.Log("pos " + Reels.transform.position.y); 
        for (int i = 0;i<5;i++)
            {
            //Direction And Speed Of Movement
            new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1, 3));
            Reels.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.smoothDeltaTime * speed, Space.World);
            
            if (Reels.transform.position.y <= 0 ) 
           {
              
            Reels.transform.position = new Vector3(Reels.transform.position.x, Reels.transform.position.y + 58, Reels.transform.position.z); 
           }
            }  
            
        }
        }

    
}
```

}

Comment: You aren't setting `position.y` to 0, you are setting it to `Reels.transform.position.y + 58` which _might_ be 0 but probably isn't.

Comment: That reffers to after, the object reaches position.y <= 0 move the object to position 58 (back up)  That works perfectly, but the if if (Reels.transform.position.y <= 0 ) is whats giving me issues. It takes as if y <= 0 was the middle of my screen.

Comment: Then it probably is the middle of the screen and you should find out what coordinates correspond with the position you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is how i solved it. I created an empty sprite on the place where i want the reel to stop, then i set the if to match that position with the position of the first sprite in the reel. If the positions match. Turn moveto to true and stop the movement

```
public class transform2 : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
public SpriteRenderer sprite1;
public SpriteRenderer[] sprites;
public SpriteRenderer cell1;
public GameObject Panel;
bool moveto;


void move()
{
    if (moveto == false)
    {
        foreach (SpriteRenderer sprites in sprites)
        {
    sprites.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.smoothDeltaTime * speed, Space.World);
    if (sprite1.transform.position.y <= cell1.transform.position.y)
    {
        moveto = true;
        sprite1.transform.position = cell1.transform.position;
    }
    Debug.Log("MOVE");
        }
    }



}
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{   
    speed = 20;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    move();
}
}
```